# SQL Query to Find Multiple Rows with Same Column Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a users table with a column called email and a column called enabled. I'm looking to find all users with the same email. If one of these users has enabled as nil, I would like to reset that user's login to its first name (another column). Note: There should be at most two users that share an email.

I'm just starting to learn SQL. How would I get this query working? I appreciate the patience!

```
update users
set users.login = users.first_name
from users u1 inner join users u2
on u1.email = u2.email 
  where u1.id != u2.id
  and u2.enabled is null
```

My RDBMS is MySQL!

Comment: What is your RDBM's? The update command will probably be different for most of then.

Comment: Great call - its MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `MySQL` then;

```
update users u1 
join users u2 on
u1.email = u2.email and u1.enable is null
set u1.login = u1.first_name
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c103c/1)